# TeamCity Database migration

Tags: sql-server, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

We have a TeamCity installation as well as an external MSSQL database on a Microsoft SQL server. We've had to migrate the database to a new instance and now have to configure TeamCity to point to the new database.

I've looked through this guide (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Manual+Backup+and+Restore) among others but they all seem needlesly complicated and seem to imply a complete relocation of the entire teamcity installation whereas we simply want to point an existing teamcity installation to a new database.

A simply search reveals a config with a connectionstring hidden in teamcity/serverdata/config. It would seem like we could simply change the config file and be done with it. Are we missing something?

We're using TeamCity Professional 2017.1 (build 46533)

Answer (score 2):

If you're only migrating to the new server, then changing configuration in `<TeamCity Data Directory>\config\database.properties` file all you have to do.

I assume that you'll make a backup, migrate data to the new database, right? After that you can safely change value in the corresponding file and restart the Teamcity. Probably make sense to check connection to the database from Teamcity server first as well.

Comment: do you need to backup and restore the database if we're about to migrate TeamCity server to another isolated server (same OS, environment) but keepthe same MSSQL database? Thanks